# python cPickle unpickling error invalid load key

Tags: python, pickle

The python object is a nested list of strings and numbers.

The file was was opened for writing as 'w' (not 'wb') but cPickle was told to use protocol=1 (so binary).

The serialization and deserialization code worked fine on Linux. I am not able to recover the objects saved on a Windows machine (Python 2.6).

I understand (now) that the file should have been opened in Windows explicitly as 'wb' because of line endings. That said the object written was a nested list and did not contain \n so I'm not sure that should matter.

My question is what can be done to recover the data?

Here is the result of `print repr(open(fqfn, 'rb').read(15))`:

```
 ']q\x01(]q\x02]q\x03(U\x0fst'
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

---

I tried `l = cPickle.load(open(fqfn, 'r'))` as [suggested by mhawke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963449), but Windows sends me an EOF error.

If I open the file directly in a hex editor, can I simply replace the instances of `'\r\n'` with `10` and `13` and then recover using the binary mode?

The input to the serialization was something like:

```
[['start', 3454654], [1234567645, -1 , 99], [1234567900, 1 , 56], ...]
```

I know the order of the input, the length of each list, and some of the values (for example the string at the beginning and some of the numbers).

So I guess my question is whether I can deserialize by writing a script that processes the binary encoding. I do not need to get it into a python object -- ascii is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might have already tried to unpickle the file by opening it in text mode `'r'` (i.e. not `'rb'`) on the Windows machine. If you're lucky the following should work:

```
import cPickle
l = cPickle.load(open(fqfn, 'r'))
```

Your data may not have contained new lines, but it might have contained values such as 10 or 13. Consider the following:

```
>>> cPickle.dumps(10, protocol=1)
'K\n.'
>>> cPickle.dumps(256, protocol=1)
'M\x00\x01.'
>>> cPickle.dumps(266, protocol=1)
'M\n\x01.'
```

The '\n' in the first one is there because ascii 10 is new line character, and the binary pickle mode stores it that way. Similarly, if you pickle 266 (256+10) you will also see '\n' in the output.

On Windows, Python automatically converts '\n' to '\r\n' when writing to a file opened in "text" mode. It also converts '\r\n' into '\n' when reading in text mode. So, opening the file in "text" mode on the Windows machine should solve your problem.